# How to apply K-mean algorithm to multidimensional array?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, matlab-guide, data-analysis

I have a matrix `A = (a1,a2,a3,...,an)'`,where `a1, a2,..., an` are row vectors. I want to apply `k-means` algorithm to matrix `A` in order to cluster the row vector `ai` `(i=1,2,3...,n)` to `k` clusters or more. Suppose `b1, b2, b3,...,bk` are the centers of `k` clusters, `k` samples are randomly selected to be the initial centers of `k` clusters. All the samples (`a1,a2,a3,...,an`) are classified according to their cosine distance to the centers `bi (i=1,2,3,...,k)` into `k` classes, that is, `k` clusters. The centers of `k` clusters are recalculated, all samples are reclassified until the centers do not change, and then the final centers `b1,b2,b3,...,bk` are obtained. For each cluster, only the vector closest to the center of cluster is retained. How to realize this?

Comment: Are you required to write all of this yourself, or are you allowed to use libraries?

Comment: @It's Magic, I am allowed to use libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`kmeans`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) function (in the *Statistics and Machine learning toolbox*) performs exactly this. Simply use:

```
C = kmeans(A, k, 'Distance', 'cosine')
```

to get the desired output.

Best,

Comment: I want to apply it to the row vector ai (i=1,2,3...,n) to k clusters or more. Not just apply it to the matrix A.  How to represent this? And I also want to realize this: for each cluster, only the vector closest to the center of cluster is retained. You mean the "C" here only gives us the "vector" closest to the center of cluster?

Comment: @Shawn Have you read the documentation of kmeans (links in the answer) ? It explains that the output `C` is a cell of arrays, each containing the indexes of the clusterized rows. It also explains that it considers the input matrix `A` as a collection of row vectors, which is, as far as I understand it, what you asked for.

Comment: @Shawn Not sure to understabd what your "nearest vector" sentence mean. I guess you can make a little post process to get the barycenters and compute the nearest vectors.

Comment: @Shawn Sorry the output of kmeans is not a cell but a vector with "_as many rows as [the input], and each row indicates the cluster assignment of the corresponding observation._"